# Connecting via nginx to secure websocket

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket

I faced problem with connecting via wss to my service, when i do it in ws way everyting is ok, but in wss I got error like:

```
 type: 'error',
    message: 'write EPROTO 584:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\\ws\\deps\\openssl\\openssl\\ssl\\record\\ssl3_record.c:332:\n',
    error: Error: write EPROTO 584:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332:

        at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:92:16) {
      errno: 'EPROTO',
      code: 'EPROTO',
      syscall: 'write'
    }
```

@edit according to my comment, I'm using this configuration for ssl in nginx:

```
location / {
proxy_set_header HOST $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_pass_request_headers on;
proxy_pass http://<server ip="">:<server port="">;
proxy_http_version 1.0;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/#comment-4370665656

@edit2

This is my nginx configuration:

```
events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##



        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This is from file nginx.conf, there is no other configuration files expect this one with websocket config.

Comment: SSLv3 has been deprecated for years.  Are you sure it's actually in use here?

Comment: @Brad I use configuration from this site https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/, look my edit

Comment: The SSL/TLS stuff will be in a different config file.  Also, I'd be surprised to see an upgrade request work on HTTP/1.0.

Comment: @Brad so what is solution for it?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't shown us the relevant config file, or even mentioned what you're connecting to this service with.  We don't even know what OS you're using, so I can't tell you where your config files likely are located.

Comment: I'm using debian, what information do you need to give me some advice? :((

Comment: Check `/etc/nginx` and see if you can find what other config files are being loaded.  Probably what you're looking for is in `nginx.conf`, and your site config is in separate files.  And, try setting `proxy_http_version` to `1.1`.  I don't know if that has any effect or not, but as I said, I don't think an HTTP upgrade request will succeed for HTTP/1.0.

Comment: @Brad Iedited  my post

Answer (score 0):

you should try

```
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
```